# Render Html by Thymeleaf not through http request

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to render a custom html file but my application not use http -> render template. I want to create dynamic template by thymeleaf not throught http request . DO you have a solution resolve it?

Comment: Please try to ask your question in a more detailed, clear way, with understandable english.

Comment: One way would be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57677561/4126893